# Java - splitting a string onto a new string?

Tags: java, regex, split

E.g.

```
String s = "You should always brush your teeth before every meal in the day.";
```

but I want do split part of it into a new sentence like so:

```
String s = "You should always brush your teeth/nbefore every meal in the day.";
```

so the result is this:

```
String s = "You should always brush your teeth";

String s2 = "before every meal in the day.";
```

Basically, I want it to search for the "**/n**" and then separate the next sentence from the present one.

Comment: Splitting the second string is easy. But if you want to split the first string, this is called *word wrapping*, which is a completely different topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] str = s.split("/n");
if(str.length == 2) {
    s = str[0];
    s2 = str[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string into an array of strings doing

```
String[] chunks = s.split("\\n");
```